# How do you link a sql server to Microsoft Access?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc

I need to create a front end interface for my database.  I am using sql server 2014 and need to link it to Microsoft access 2016.  Please note that the two applications are on separate machines.  So far I have created a a file DSN on the machine with sql server and the connection was successful.  Within access I used the ODBC database tool to attempt to use the dsn I created to connect to the server.  I received an error sql state '08001' sql error:-1 as seen in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6MxO.png).  how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please post the error as text, at least the full title - `Connection failed: sql state '08001'`

Comment: http://knowhow.visual-paradigm.com/hibernate/solving-sql-server-connection-problem/  and plenty of other resources when you search for "sql server Connection failed".

Answer (score 1):

> I have created a a file DSN on the machine with sql server and the connection was successful. Within access I used the ODBC database tool to attempt to use the dsn I created to connect to the server

That's not how it works. You create the DSN on the machine that will act as the client, not the machine that will act as the server.

In other words, a DSN needs to be created on the machine(s) running Access, not the machine running SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear. The server is off-line or not reachable in some other way.

It's a network issue, not a coding issue, so debug this with your *network guy* m/f.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a new ODBC connection on your computer.  I'm not sure what operating system you have, but assuming it's Microsoft Windows then it should be located in your Control Panel.  During setup you will be able to test if the connection is successful.  If it is, there's no reason you can't use that ODBC connection in your Access application when you link to the SQL Server database.  If the test fails, then there is an issue with the SQL Server which should be addressed with your IT department.